# custom UIView view does not respond to "release"

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom uiview class that implements `drawRect` and is an IBoutlet to my interface builder. I assume this is a pretty standard way of implementing custom views that do their own drawing.

Now, I'm doing my good deed to release all IBOutlets in my view controller's `dealloc` - however, i noticed that custom view classes do not respond to `release` - now why would this be? they inherit from UIView, so why does the xcode code sense feature not provide `release` on them? is it not necessary or possible to release them from memory?

Comment: What makes you think that they don't respond to `release`? Are you getting an error?

Comment: i discovered my issue... for this particular iboutlet, i needed `self.` in front it before releasing. it wouldn't not accept `release` without that; even though the other outlets didn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release the view and set the view variable to nil in the viewDidUnload method of your view controller.
The viewDidUnload method is the recommended place to release IBOutlets.